# Jquery attr() funciton returning "undefined" for GetCapabilities Request

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, jquery

On my webpage where I am displaying my maps, I want to add a link to the metadata of the selected map. 
I have specified the link in GeoServer in the MetaDataURL field, and should be able to retrieve it with a GET request and finding it in the XML(See below for XML and Jquery code)
But every time I test it I get "undefined"...which is very strange, it seems as if the attribute doesn't even exist. Does anyone have a clue why it returns "undefined"

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://fast.openearth.eu/geoserver/wms?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities",
        dataType: "xml",
                       success: function(xml) {
                                               $(xml).find('Layer').each(function(){
                                                     if ($(this).children("Title").text() == layer.name) {
MetaDataURL = $(this).children("MetadataURL").children("OnlineResource").attr("xlink:href");
}});}});

<Layer queryable="1">
                                                                                                                                    <Name>Global:wcmc-010-mangroveusgs2011</Name>
<Title>Mangrove USGS2011</Title>
<Abstract>Giri C, Ochieng E, Tieszen LL, Zhu Z, Singh A, Loveland T, Masek J, Duke N (2011).&#13;
    Status and distribution of mangrove forests of the world using earth observation&#13;
    satellite data. Global Ecology and Biogeography 20: 154-159. URL:&#13;
    http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1466-8238.2010.00584.x/abstract ;&#13;
    http://data.unep-wcmc.org/datasets/4</Abstract>
<KeywordList>
<Keyword>wcmc-010-mangroveusgs2011</Keyword>
<BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84" minx="-180.537994384766" miny="-35.6819496154785" maxx="181.735992431641" maxy="30.3975315093994"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326" minx="-35.6819496154785" miny="-180.537994384766" maxx="30.3975315093994" maxy="181.735992431641"/>
<MetadataURL type="ISO19115:2003">
<Format>text/plain</Format>
<OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://fast.openearth.eu/geonetwork/srv/eng/metadata.show?id=39&amp;currTab=simple"/>
</MetadataURL>
```

Comment: Use your browser's debugger to find which bit you got wrong exactly.

Comment: Good tip! Sadly though I'm not getting any errors...I entered a breakpoint, and starting following what is happening, but it just dives really deep into Jquery source code...too heavy for me. It still is strange that when I access the text (.text()) of an element, I get a result, but no matter which attribute I select in the XML, it returns "undefined"...Very strange indeed.